# uNet to Mirror Migration (2 errors)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet, unity3d-mirror

I have two problems to solve. The first is
`error CS0115: 'NetworkManagerSample.OnServerDisconnect(NetworkConnection)': no suitable method found to override` And the second is `The type or namespace name 'MessageBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Help please, it’s very important. [Errors In code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMW5m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

```
    public override void OnServerDisconnect(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
    {
    base.OnServerDisconnect(conn);
    }
```

Secondly:

Do you have using MessageBase; written at the top of a script? Maybe just remove it? Or add in a namespace of MessageBase.

Comment: Thanks, first issue was fixed.
Secondly: I'm using MessageBase in BaseClientSocket (from MSF asset)
I need to migrate it full to stay working.